# Angular 2+: isolate child model from parent model

Tags: angular

I have this parent component

```
@component({
 selector: 'parent',
 template: '<child [data]="data"></child>'
})
class Parent {
 private data = {
  name: 'name',
  age: 'age'
 }
}
```

And this child component

```
@component({
 selector: 'child',
 template: '
  <form>
   <input type="text" [ngModel]="data.name" />
   <input type="submit" value="ok" (click)="onSubmit()"/>
  </form>'
})
class Child {
 @Input data;
 @output dataChange = new EventEmitter();

 onSubmit () {
  this.dataChange.emit(this.data);
 }
```

Currently, when I type something in the child input, it changes the `data.name` in parent component. Is there a simple way to avoid this, and change `data.name` in parent only when form is submitted ? Or do i have to use libs like immutable or object cloning ?
Thanks

Comment: `ngOnInit`, spread operator and private variable will help you, if object is nested one level down. Or you can deep copy object before or after binding

Comment: That's what i was afraid of. There is no way angular could handle this by itself ?

Comment: Nope, you could use reactive form and patch form value with the `data`